# Lumen after upgradation from 5.7 to 6.0 db:seed command not working

Tags: composer-php, lumen, laravel-6

I have upgraded from Lumen 5.7 to 6.0. After the upgradation, the `artisan db:seeder` command is not working. It shows  `Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist`. I have tried running `composer dump-autoload` but it didn't solve the problem. Below is the composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel",
        "lumen"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^6.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": []
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Please help

Comment: Remove `vendor` folder and install and try again

Comment: I tried removing the vendor folder and composer.lock files, but no luck

Comment: Did you copy and paste `composer.json` 5.6 to 6?

Comment: Edited composer.json `"laravel/lumen-framework": "^6.0",`. When I try it in my Windows system it is working. The issue is only on the CentOS Linux 7 (Core) server

Answer (score 0):

Laravel changed directory of seeders class, (from database/seeds to database/seeders) so you probably need to update your composer.json this way (move seeders in autoload /psr-4):

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

And add namespace to your seeders files :

```
<?php
  
namespace Database\Seeders;
  
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
  
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
....
```

Don't forget to run `composter dump-autoload` after updating your files.